# How to make my css selector engine more flexible?

Tags: javascript, dom, css-selectors

I created a custom css selector engine function for my custom javascript library like so,

```
var catchEl = function(el) { // Catching elements by identifying the first character of a string

var firstChar = el[0], 
   actualNode = el.substring(1, el.length),
   elements,
   tempElems = [];

if (!document.querySelectorAll) {
   try{
       if(firstChar === "#") {//So, we can look for ids
          tempElems.push(document.getElementById(actualNode));
       } else if(firstChar === ".") {//or classes
          elements = document.getElementsByClassName(actualNode);
          for(i=0;i<elements.length;i++) tempElems.push(elements[i]);
       } else {//or tags
          elements = document.getElementsByTagName(el);
          for(i=0;i<elements.length;i++) tempElems.push(elements[i]);
       }
   } catch(e) {};
} else {//but before everything we must check if the best function is available
   try{
      elements = document.querySelectorAll(el);
      for(i=0;i<elements.length;i++) tempElems.push(elements[i]);
   } catch(e) {};
}
return tempElems;
}
```

This function returns an array of elements. However, I turned my head around and tried to make it more flexible so that it can also return the `window`, `document` or `this` object, but was unsuccessful. Whenever I try to `push` the `window` object into the `tempElems` array, the array is still empty.

So, I want to know how to make this function return an array of elements when a string is passed through it or return the respective objects(`window`, `document` or `this`) as desired.

Note: I don't want to work with jQuery. So, please don't post any answers regarding jQuery.

Comment: you should read John Resig's "Secrets of the JavaScript Ninja" book, he is the creator of jquery and this book specificly walks you through creating a css selector engine.

Comment: This question doesn't belong in Stackoverflow as it's not a straight Q&A with a single answer.  It's probably better in http://codereview.stackexchange.com.